# Mongoose $gt with Date returning $gte results

Tags: date, datetime, mongoose

I have some code that is trying to get all documents of type Post after a specified time.

Post is defined as such: {
    updated : Date
    }

when I run the following:

Post.find ( { updated : { $gt : specifiedDate } } )

Where specifiedDate is a Date object with value less than new Date(), it returns Post documents that HAVE updated = specifiedDate, instead of all Posts with updated AFTER specifiedDate.

So, it seems to be returning results for a $gte query, instead of $gt.

Has anyone else observed this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

If it helps to clarify the situation, the Date object is encoded and sent in the request as a parameter as timestamp. I'm trying to get all Posts that are "new", meaning all after the date of the last visible post. This Date object is the timestamp that is set as req.params.timestamp. There is ONE Post document that has the same Date as what is passed as req.params.timestamp. All Posts after this should be returned, however, this Post keeps showing up as if I'm calling $gte instead of $gt.

Here's the query:

```
Post.find({$or : [{_recipient : user.id}, {_sender : user.id, mode : POST_MODE.POST}], updated : { $gt : new Date (decodeURIComponent(req.params.timestamp)) }})
.sort({updated : -1})
```

When I check console for

```
new Date (decodeURIComponent(req.params.timestamp))
```

... it is formatted down to the millisecond as

```
Wed Apr 23 2014 15:03:52 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

Answer (score 0):

So my guess is you are thinking in days and not realizing that if `specifiedDate` is midnight at the instance a day begins, all posts updated any time during that day are considered "greater than" as far as mongodb is concerned. Perhaps you need to use midnight of the day AFTER `specifiedDate` in your query and change your operator to `$gte`? Remember a Date in JavaScript has precision down to the millisecond, so for 2 dates to be equal, they have to occur at the exact same millisecond, which is what leads me to my theory that you are thinking in days instead of milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I should have clarified that I am thinking in milliseconds. I checked the two values of the date object stored in updated, and the date object sent in the query and both have the exact same value down to the split second. I have a Post in my collection with that updated value, and it is being returned when I use $gt. Which is why I'm concluding something's messed up, since it's acting like $gte. I hope not though :/

Comment: Second guess: utc vs local time zone?

Comment: I'll try converting both to utc

Comment: I added 1 millisecond to the specifiedDate parameter, and it worked (returning only Posts after the specifiedDate), where the comparison operator was $gt (NOT $gte). I think this may be a bug. However, it looks no one else has come across this. Anyone?

Comment: I just updated my package to install mongoose 3.8.8 (it was at 3.8.1 previously), and the issue is still occurring. Well, for now I'll use my workaround.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I am having the same issue. Adding a (milli)second to my date object fixes it, but that's not a great fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem that seemed to be the same. I am posting this although I am not sure if it is the same problem because I just spent a lot of time on it and it might help somebody else.

In my case a unit test failed because it returned the document although using `$gt` on the date attribute and putting the same date object as used to save the document in the query.

When I just put the date in the query sent with Chai it failed and also using `moment.utc`.

At least with `moment.utc` it seemed to get truncated to seconds because I had to add a second for it to work with `$gt`. Adding less, for example 100 milliseconds did not work.

But using the method `toISOString()` on the Date object and passing the result to the query worked with `$gt` as expected.